# text_extends behaves unexpected when i try to render a png, is this a bug?

Tags: png, cairo, pycairo

I noticed lately that in some cases the png will look differently as the pdf. I rendered the preview images in different sizes an realized that the output could be totally different for the same input when I change the output size of the surface.

The problem is, that text_extends reports different normalized sizes for the same text when the surface pixel size is different. In this example the width varies from 113.861 to 120.175. Since I have to write each line separately those errors are some times much bigger in total.

Has anybody an idea how avoid those miscalculation?

Here is a small demonstration of this problem

```
import cairo
form StringIO import StringIO

def render_png(width, stream):
    width_px = height_px = width
    surface = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, width_px, height_px)
    cr = cairo.Context(surface)
    cr.scale(float(width_px) / float(100),
             float(height_px) / float(100))
    cr.set_antialias(cairo.ANTIALIAS_GRAY)

    cr.set_source_rgb (1, 1, 1)
    cr.rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100) 
    cr.fill()

    cr.select_font_face('Zapfino Extra LT') # a fancy font
    cr.set_font_size(20)
    example_string = 'Ein belieber Test Text'
    xbearing, ybearing, width, height, xadvance, yadvance = (
                        cr.text_extents(example_string))
    xpos = (100. - width) / 2. # centering text
    print width

    cr.move_to(xpos,50)
    cr.set_source_rgba(0,0,0)
    cr.show_text(example_string)

    surface.write_to_png(stream)
    return width

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l=[]
    for i in range(100,150,1):
        outs=StringIO()
        xpos = render_png(i,outs)
        l.append((i,xpos))
        #out = open('/home/hwmrocker/Desktop/FooBar/png_test%03d.png'%i, 'w')
        #outs.seek(0)
        #out.write(outs.read())
        #out.close()

    from operator import itemgetter
    l=sorted(l,key=itemgetter(1))
    print
    print l[0]
    print l[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is likely due to the nature of text rendering itself - as glyphs in a font depend are drawn in different ways, depending on the pixel resolution. More so when the pixel resolution is small when compared to the glyph sizes (I'd say less than 30px height per glyph). This behavior is to be expected to some extend - always in order to prioritize readability of the text. If it is too off - or the png text is "uglier" than on the PDF (instead of incorrect size), then iis a bug in Cairo. Nevertheless, you probably should place this exact question on Cairo's issue tracker, so that the developers can tell wether it is a bug or not (and if it is, it maybe  the only possible way for they to get aware of it)
(Apparently they have no public bug tracker - just e-mail it to cairo-bugs@cairographics.org )

As for your specific problem, the workaround I will suggest to you is to render your text to a larger surface -- maybe 5 times larger, and resize that surface and paste the contents on your original surface (if needed at all). This way you might avoid glyph-size variations due to constraints in the number of pixels available for each glyph (at the cost of having a poorer text rendering on your final output).

Comment: In time: text size variations due to resolution is also font-dependent. Try changing your font just as an experiment.